# Django: Checkbox not showing up in HTML

Tags: python, html, django

This form has multiple choices to select from. However the check boxes don't show up in HTML! I'm using Materialise CSS. Please help.

forms.py:

```
FAVORITE_COLORS_CHOICES = (
('blue', 'Blue'),
('green', 'Green'),
('black', 'Black'),
)

class StudentForm(forms.ModelForm):
    favorite_colors = forms.MultipleChoiceField(
        required=False,
        widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple,
        choices=FAVORITE_COLORS_CHOICES,
    )
```

form.html:

```
<div class="container">
<form>

{{ form.as_p }}

<input type='submit' value='Save' />

</form>
```

HTML page in browser:

[image: HTML page in browser:]

View-source from browser:

```
<form>

    <p><label for="id_student_name">Student name:</label> <input type="text" name="student_name" maxlength="200" required id="id_student_name"></p>
<p><label for="id_present">Present:</label> <input type="checkbox" name="present" required id="id_present"></p>
<p><label>Favorite colors:</label> <ul id="id_favorite_colors">
    <li><label for="id_favorite_colors_0"><input type="checkbox" 
name="favorite_colors" value="blue" id="id_favorite_colors_0">
 Blue</label>

</li>
    <li><label for="id_favorite_colors_1"><input type="checkbox" 
name="favorite_colors" value="green" id="id_favorite_colors_1">
 Green</label>

</li>
    <li><label for="id_favorite_colors_2"><input type="checkbox" 
name="favorite_colors" value="black" id="id_favorite_colors_2">
 Black</label>

</li>
</ul></p>

    <input type='submit' value='Save' />

    </form>
```

Updated:

```
 {% for field in form %}
        <p>
            <input type="checkbox" id=field />
        <label for=field>Hello</label>
        </p>
    {% endfor %}
```

Comment: It would be much more useful to see the actual html text, rather than a picture of the rendered html...

Comment: @thebjorn actual HTML text as in the HTML code? HTML code and python code are above the screenshot. If its not that code, what do you mean by "html text"?

Comment: What you have in `form.html` is the Django template code (it contains `{{ form.as_p }}`. We need to see what it generated, perhaps by using your browser's view-source functionality. Also, have you used your browser's "Inspect Element" function to examine which styles are being applied?

Comment: @thebjorn I added the view source from browser. And it says Materalise CSS is being applied. What's really strange is that in inspect element there is an checkbox input element so its just not showing up on the page itself for some reason.

Answer (score 2):

The fundamental problem is that Django outputs your color options like this:

```
  <!-- default Django -->
  <li>
    <label for="id_favorite_colors_1">
      <input type="checkbox" name="favorite_colors" value="green" id="id_favorite_colors_1">
      Green
    </label>
  </li>
```

..and of course for singular checkbox fields, Django outputs:

```
<p>
    <label for="id_present">Present:</label>
    <input type="checkbox" name="present" required id="id_present">
</p>
```

while Materialize expects to see them like this (note the `<span>` around the word "Blue"):

```
  <!-- correct Materialize -->
  <li>
    <label for="id_favorite_colors_0">
      <input type="checkbox" name="favorite_colors" value="blue" id="id_favorite_colors_0">
      <span>Blue</span>
    </label>
  </li>
```

jsfiddle (https://jsfiddle.net/8eamw6dg/)

I'm afraid the only solution Django has here is to manually render the fields (docs: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/#rendering-fields-manually). I.e. instead of

```
<form>
{{ form.as_p }}
<input type='submit' value='Save' />
</form>
```

you would need something like

```
<form>
{{ form.non_field_errors }}
<p>... student name field here ...</p>

<p>
    {{ form.present.errors }}
    <label for="{{ form.present.id_for_label }}">
        {{ form.present }}
        <span>{{ form.present.label }}</span>
    </label>
</p>

etc. for all the other fields...

<input type='submit' value='Save' />
</form>
```

Comment: I'm not quite sure how I would go around to implementing that. Could you please provide an example? And I also need there to be only one checkbox because it is for a present/absent checkbox. Do you have any tips on the best way to implement that? And sorry for such silly and simple questions! I'm new to programming.

Comment: @Egor.L I've updated my answer. Read the Django documentation I linked to for much more details.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue. If you are using material frontend you can render it in this way:

```
{% load material_form %}
...
<form method="get">
    {% form form=form %}{% endform %}
    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-default" value='send' />
</form>
```

Answer (score 2):

### The Issue:

---

@thebjorn answer is right, the issue is that materialize is expecting the HTML for your checkbox to be something like this

```
<label for="id_favorite_colors_0">
  <input type="checkbox" name="favorite_colors" id="id_favorite_colors_0">
  <span> Blue </span>
</label>
```

but by default Django renders checkboxes like this

```
<label for="id_favorite_colors_0">
  <input type="checkbox" name="favorite_colors" id="id_favorite_colors_0">
</label>
```

The `<span>` element is indeed required so that materialize can render the radio button properly.

### The Solution

---

One way to get Django to use the expected HTML is to overwrite the default widget for checkbox fields, to do that, you will need to do 3 things.

First, create a new class that inherits from `CheckboxSelectMultiple` and overwrite the `option_template_name` attribute so that it points to our new custom HTML

project/widgets.py

```
from django import forms
class MaterialCheckboxSelectMultiple(forms.widgets.CheckboxSelectMultiple):
    option_template_name = 'project/widgets/material_checkbox.html'
```

then we create the HTML file with our materialize compatible implementation for checkboxes
note: For this example, I will just add the span element to the original implementation)

project/widgets/material_checkbox.html:

```
{% if widget.wrap_label %}
  <label{% if widget.attrs.id %} for="{{ widget.attrs.id }}"{% endif %}>
{% endif %}
{% include "django/forms/widgets/input.html" %}
<span> {{ widget.label }} </span>
{% if widget.wrap_label %}
  </label>
{% endif %}
```

Finally, all you need to do is to use the newly created widget in your checkbox field definition:

project/forms.py:

```
from  .widgets import MaterialCheckboxSelectMultiple

FAVORITE_COLORS_CHOICES = (
('blue', 'Blue'),
('green', 'Green'),
('black', 'Black'),
)

class StudentForm(forms.ModelForm):
    favorite_colors = forms.MultipleChoiceField(
        required=False,
        widget=MaterialCheckboxSelectMultiple,
        choices=FAVORITE_COLORS_CHOICES,
    )
```

Answer (score 1):

The way Django generates HTML code for checkboxes is different than the way that **materialize css** expects.
One way to solving this is the **django-material** library.

Steps:

1. **pip install **django-material****
2. **Add "material" Add it into INSTALLED_APPS settings.**

   ```
   INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'material',
    ...
   ```

   )
3. **Include javascript and styles in your code.**

   {% include 'material/includes/material_css.html' %}

   {% include 'material/includes/material_js.html' %}
4. **Load the material_form template tag library.**

   {% load material_form %}
5. **And render your form with {% form %} template tag.**

   ```
   {% csrf_token %}

   {% form form=form %}{% endform %}

   <button type="submit" name="_submit" class="btn">Submit</button>
   ```

Comment: This did it for me! Thanks!

Comment: Peace !!!!!!!!!!

Answer (score 0):

Materialize CSS requires check-boxes to be inside label elements and next with a span element next to the input element. Using Django's `{{ form.as_p }}` does not include the span element and results in check-boxes not displaying correctly. You will need to split each field in the form up separately (a for loop will work as well).

```
{% for field in form %}
    <label>
        <input type="checkbox">
        <span>{{ field.name }}</span>
    </label
{% endfor %}
```

Updated above code. I think field.name will work but might be different naming (like field.value idk)

Comment: that doesn't work but I rewrote the code. The updated coded is in the original question under "updated". I only need one checkbox and it should return True or False. How would I go about doing that? I have no clue whatsoever how to achieve that.

Comment: And would this code go between `<form> </form>` tags?

Comment: Yes. You can use it outside if you want /need to. The form tags don't really effect the outcome here.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your problem correctly, below is what I faced and fixed:

In this scenario, Django was rendering labels with css 'disply:none' so the checkboxes, radio selects and dropdown choices were not getting displayed for me.

I wrote a simple javascript to fix this in my template:

```
var elems = document.querySelectorAll('label.form-check-label');
for (i = 0; i < elems.length; i++) {
elems[i].style.display = "inline";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I used class-based views in Django, with the UpdateView class.
To avoid having to change the html emitted by Django, I added the
following modification (done with JQuery) in the template:

```
{% extends "main.html" %}
{% load static %}

{% block title %}FEI Project Update{% endblock %}

{% block content %}

{# I copied the javascript libraries into the Django static area #}

<script src="{% static 'js/jquery-3.5.1.min.js' %}"></script>
<script src="{% static 'js/materialize.min.js' %}"></script>
<script src="{% static 'js/init.js' %}"></script>

{# these lines modify the html from Django and add the <label> and <span>
  statements as described above. Three lines are needed, the ones between
  <script> and </script>. Then the table can be rendered with the Django
  {{ form }} statement without any other changes. #}

<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $(':checkbox').wrap('<label class="crutch"> </label>');
        $('.crutch').append('<span> </span>');
    });
</script>

{# This is the rest of the template for illustration #}
<div class="section no-pad-top" id="index-banner">
    <style>
        table, th, td {
          border: 1px solid black;
          border-collapse: collapse;
        }
        th, td {
            text-align: center;
        }
        label {
            pointer-events: auto;
        }

    </style>
                
    <div class="container">
        <h3>FEI Project Update: {{ project_instance.sap_id }}</h3>
    
        <form action="" method="post">
            {% csrf_token %}
            <table>
                {{ form }}
            </table>
            <input type="submit" value="Submit">
        </form>
    </div>
</div>    
{% endblock %}
```